# How to properly add 1 month to current date in moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I read in the documentation of moment.js that if you want to add 1 month to the current date, you can use this code:

```js
var moment = require('moment');
var futureMonth = moment().add(1, 'M').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

But the problem is that this does not add the way I'm expecting it to. For example, let's say the current date is 31/10/2015 (the last day in the month of October). In code:

```js
var currentDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var futureMonth = moment().add(1, 'M').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

console.log(currentDate) //  Result --> 31/10/2015
console.log(futureMonth) //  Result --> 30/11/2015
```

If you take a look at the calendar date, 1 month/ 31 days from 31/10/2015 should be 1/12/2015 (the first day of December), not 30/11/2015 (the last day of November).

Could anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: I got the idea from the current calendar time, if thats what you are asking for.

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is `moment().add(30, "days")`.

Comment: @Gesper I thought moment.js define the month by itself without me needing to define it.

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh I could do that, but it won't be flexible.

Comment: @Jamiec Where is your answer, seems like you have taken it down?

Comment: What is the rule that you actually want? Is it "Add the number of days *in the current month*"? Is it "Add 1 month + 1 day"?

Comment: seems like the definition in momentjs is that if you have end-of-month and add 1 month, it will do end-of-next-month. Which seems very sane and predictable to me

Comment: @JackMoscovi check my answer, I updated it so that it fits your needs.

Comment: A month is not always 30 days long, so `moment().add(30, "days")` isn't technically the right answer.

Comment: Please do not call not proper things as proper. I suggest to change title of the question somehow. Currently it is misleading.

Comment: Change the title to "How to add a month to end of the current month?"
Your expected behaviour is NOT proper and title is misleading.

Comment: @JackMoscovi, There has to be weird boundary conditions around month addition. `2015-10-31 + 1 month` I think should be in November.(Otherwise, it might feel like 2 months to some). If you insist that two consecutive days should not have the same "one more month day"), then I would ask you what `2015-01-31 + one month` is compared to `2015-02-01 + one month` should be.

Comment: arbitrarily adding 30 days is insane. its predictable but insane

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
var currentDate = moment('2015-10-30');
var futureMonth = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'M');
var futureMonthEnd = moment(futureMonth).endOf('month');

if(currentDate.date() != futureMonth.date() && futureMonth.isSame(futureMonthEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))) {
    futureMonth = futureMonth.add(1, 'd');
}

console.log(currentDate);
console.log(futureMonth);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/butuduhoti/edit?js,console)</kbd>

**EDIT**

```
moment.addRealMonth = function addRealMonth(d) {
  var fm = moment(d).add(1, 'M');
  var fmEnd = moment(fm).endOf('month');
  return d.date() != fm.date() && fm.isSame(fmEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) ? fm.add(1, 'd') : fm;  
}

var nextMonth = moment.addRealMonth(moment());
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/deduyoroso/edit?js,console)</kbd>

Comment: Just wondering is this code flexible? or its just fix the current date problem 31/10/2015 - 1/12/2015?

Comment: This just goes wrong another way - July & August both have 31 days. When you add one month to July 31st you'll get 1st September.

Comment: Wow I tested on the last of January which is 31 and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 66):

> According to the latest [doc](https://momentjs.com/) you can do the following-

**Add a day**

```
moment().add(1, 'days').calendar();
```

**Add Year**

```
moment().add(1, 'years').calendar();
```

**Add Month**

```
moment().add(1, 'months').calendar();
```

Comment: this answer is wrong and does not correctly add a month according to the request above

Comment: Try `moment('2020-03-30').add(1, 'months')` and then compare with `moment('2020-03-31').add(1, 'months')`. The result will be the same, which is wrong.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk Pl. report here - https://github.com/moment/moment/issues

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
moment().add(1, 'M').subtract(1, 'day').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
startDate = "20.03.2020";
var newDate = moment(startDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(5, 'days');
console.log(newDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It says add 1 month and you add 4 days