# Angular 7 Hide a div when created time is more than 6 months

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In Angular 7 i want to hide a div based on the time created ,if it is past 6 months then i want to hide a div how to modify html to hide the div when the time created is more than 6 months

HTML.

```html
<div class="request"  *ngIf="request.status != 'CANCELLED' && request.duration">
```

Typescript
/** Load duration of a task */

```js
private getRequestDuration(request) {
    let createdDate = new Date(request.createTime);
    let timeInMilliSeconds = this.currentDate.getTime() - createdDate.getTime();
    let seconds = timeInMilliSeconds / 1000;
    let minutes = seconds / 60;
    let hours = minutes / 60 + 5; // FIXME: EST Offset
    hours = hours > 0 ? hours : 0; // FIXME: Hack to address time-stamp conversions / daylight savings time
    let days = hours / 24;
    return (days q> 0 ? Math.floor(days) + ' days, ' : '') + Math.floor(hours % 24) + ' hours';
}
requests.duration = this.getRequestDuration(requests);

Request Object
Object
agingCurrent: 121777671
agingTotal: 121902671
createTime: "2020-09-14T06:49:20"
createdBySso: "503184132"
duration: "1 days, 20 hours"
indErrored: false
indSavedToMdm: "TRUE"
indSubscribed: "TRUE"
partyId: "160598"
requestId: 627723
requestType: "Internal subscribe"
riskCategory: "ONE"
riskLevel: "MODERATE"
state: {status: "Active", label: "-"}
status: "APPROVED"
statusUpdateTime: "2020-09-14T06:51:25"
supplierId: "S18961"
supplierName: "LM Wind Power (Spain) SA"
transactionId: null
type: "SUBSCRIBE_INTERNAL"
updateTime: "2020-09-14T06:51:25"
version: 15
```

Comment: Why don't you use moment.js. Its perfect for this sort of thing. Here is a SO post about how to use it too.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440646/how-to-properly-add-1-month-from-now-to-current-date-in-moment-js

Comment: Hi Darren Property 'getMonth' does not exist on type 'DateConstructor'.ts(2339)

Comment: How to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

**Inside .ts file**

```
public date = new Date();
public six_month_before_date = this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() - 6);
//**convert request.createTime to Date object before compare**//
request.createTime=new Date(request.createTime)
```

**Inside .html file**

```
<div class="request"  *ngIf="request.createTime>six_month_before_date">
<!-Only then display data-->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sanjay let me try

Comment: where excatly in .ts file should i write that function you gave

Comment: shall i create any method like private    six_month_before_date=new Date()
  six_month_before_date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -6);// minus six month

Comment: Hi Sanjay Property 'getMonth' does not exist on type 'DateConstructor'.ts(2339) how to resolve this error

Comment: public date=new Date()
public six_month_before_date=date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -6);

Comment: Hi Sanjay is the html ngIf condition correct because rite now all the data is hidden when i write like this <div class="request"  *ngIf="request.createTime>six_month_before_date">

Comment: Sanjay can you help me with ngIf condition please

Comment: can you share the request object? I just want to see what exactly it contained

Comment: *ngIf  condition is correct.there may be a problem with the request object

Comment: sure Sanjay i will share you the request object

Comment: Object
agingCurrent: 121777671
agingTotal: 121902671
createTime: "2020-09-14T06:49:20"
createdBySso: "503184132"
duration: "1 days, 20 hours"
indErrored: false
indSavedToMdm: "TRUE"
indSubscribed: "TRUE"
partyId: "160598"
requestId: 627723
requestType: "Internal subscribe"
riskCategory: "ONE"
riskLevel: "MODERATE"
state: {status: "Active", label: "-"}
status: "APPROVED"
statusUpdateTime: "2020-09-14T06:51:25"
supplierId: "S18961"
supplierName: "LM Wind Power (Spain) SA"
transactionId: null
type: "SUBSCRIBE_INTERNAL"
updateTime: "2020-09-14T06:51:25"
version: 15

Comment: Hi Sanjay i had added the request object in the question updated. can you help me with ngIf condition please help me sir

Comment: Hi sanjay it is based on duration: "1 days, 20 hours" not created time , so how to mofidy ngIf condition

Comment: ok got it, you don't need to calculate the duration. Just covert the createTime property to a Date object.

Comment: Hi Sanjay where exactly should i place that code in ts file . its throwing errors public date = new Date();
public six_month_before_date = this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() - 6);
request.createTime=new Date(request.createTime)