# UI Kitten calendar future years disabled

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

Does anyone understand why the [UI Kitten Calendar component](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/calendar/overview#calendar) is only enabled for the current year? It's 2021 now and when I try to select a day from future or past years in the demo live view for "Simple Usage", they are disabled..

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there are 2 props `startDate` and `endDate` props you can specify like this

```js
export interface CalendarRange<D> {
  startDate?: D;
  endDate?: D;
}
```

```js
<Calendar
  date={date}
  onSelect={nextDate => setDate(nextDate)}
  endDate={endDate} <------ add this
/>
```

for the value of `endDate` I think you can have a look at [How to properly add 1 month from now to current date in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440646/how-to-properly-add-1-month-from-now-to-current-date-in-moment-js) because KittenUI calendar is using moment.js.